# How to get the version list and latest version of NuGet in VS Code?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget, vscode-extensions, blazor

Currently, I am working on the Visual Studio Code extension support. In my case, I need to install my latest `NuGet` packages from Online to the VSCode `Blazor` projects. Could you please suggest me how can I get the all published `NuGet` packages based on the `NuGet` package name and latest `NuGet` version of the package using typescript ? Since I need the logic for the Visual Studio Code, I can't use the `C#` Visual Studio logic in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

#### How-to

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-autocomplete-service-resource#enumerate-package-versions), you can send a HTTP GET request to this endpoint to enumerate the package versions :

```
GET {@id}?id={ID}&prerelease={PRERELEASE}&semVerLevel={SEMVERLEVEL}
```

e.g . By sending a request to :

```
https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/autocomplete?id=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor&prerelease=true&semVerLevel=2
```

You can enumerate the packages as below :

```
{"@context":{"@vocab":"http://schema.nuget.org/schema#"},"totalHits":1,"data":["0.1.0","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.5.0","0.5.1","0.6.0","0.7.0","0.8.0-preview-19075-0444","0.8.0-preview-19104-04","0.9.0-preview3-19153-02","0.9.0-preview3-19154-02","3.0.0-preview4-19216-03","3.0.0-preview5-19227-01","3.0.0-preview6.19307.2","3.0.0-preview7.19365.7","3.0.0-preview8.19405.7","3.0.0-preview9.19424.4","3.0.0-preview9.19457.4","3.0.0-preview9.19465.2","3.1.0-preview1.19508.20"]}
```

And in order to get such a base url, you can send a request to `ServiceIndex` and query the `@id` where its `@type` equals `SearchAutocompleteService` or `SearchAutocompleteService/3.0.0-beta` or `SearchAutocompleteService/3.0.0-rc`. For more details, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-autocomplete-service-resource#versioning

---

#### Demo:

```js
interface ItemDescription {
    "@id": String;
    "@type": String;
    "comment": String;
}
interface ServiceIndexResponse {
    version: String;
    resources: ItemDescription[];
} ;

interface PackageVersionsResponse{
    "@context": any;
    "totalHits": Number;
    "data": String[];
}

function enumeratePackageVersion(packageId: String, prerelease: Boolean, semVerLevel? : string){
    var serviceIndexUrl = "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json";
    return fetch(serviceIndexUrl,{})
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then((r: ServiceIndexResponse) => {
            let typeName ="SearchAutocompleteService" ;
            let queries = r.resources.filter(item => item["@type"] == typeName);
            if(queries.length == 0) throw new Error(`unable to get the ${typeName} from ServiceIndex`);
            var serviceUrl = queries[0]["@id"];
            return serviceUrl;
        })
        .then(serviceUrl =>{
            var query = `id=${packageId}&prerelease=${prerelease}`;
            if(semVerLevel){
                query = query + `&semVerLevel=${semVerLevel}`;
            }
            return fetch(`${serviceUrl}?${query}`,{})
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then((r: PackageVersionsResponse) => r.data);
}
```

And invoke the function as below:

```js
enumeratePackageVersion("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor", true, "2.0.0")
    .then(r =>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
    });
```

---

**[Edit]**

The above code assume you're using a fetch api. You can follow these steps to use the `node-fetch`:

1. install the `node-fetch` by `npm i node-fetch --save`
2. install the type declarations package by `npm i @types/node-fetch --save-dev`
3. import the fetch by `import fetch from "node-fetch";`

**Screenshot of Demo**
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the solution which is suggested above but this is not working for me. I have followed the below steps. Used the above code in my typescript file and then, I have installed the "node-fetch" NPM since I have faced the issue "cannot find name 'fetch'". Then, I have added the below line in header.    import fetch from "node-fetch" and invoke the function using enumeratePackageVersion() But my code is not running after the line return fetch(URL,{}).Could you please suggest what i have done wrong.

Comment: @Karthi you need add the type declarations too. For example, install `@types/node-fetch`. See my updated answer for more details.